# Database error: no such table: auth_user. Extending AbstractUser and using model to register on admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-authentication, django-syncdb

I'm trying to use AbstractUser to add a field to Django's standard User model. This is my code:

```
class GUser(AbstractUser):
    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True)
```

This has been successful because from the shell I can say,

```
>>> a = GUser.objects.all()

>>> a
[<GUser: User1>]

>>> a[0].uuid
UUID('7d1f0b7b52144a2ea20db81ce74741e3')
```

The problem I am having is registering a new user from the /admin. When I create a new user I get a Database error:

```
no such table: auth_user
```

Before I get more into it, here is my forms.py:

```
class GUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

class GUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

    def clean_username(self):
            username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
            try:
                get_user_model().objects.get(username=username)
            except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
                return username
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate'])
```

And my admin.py:

```
class GUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = GUserChangeForm
    add_form = GUserCreationForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': [('username', 'password')]}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('is_active','is_staff','is_superuser','groups',    'user_permissions')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        #('Universal ID', {'fields': ('uuid')})
        )

admin.site.register(GUser,GUserAdmin)
```

I read that when this has happened to other people they implemented their own Forms (as I did) to overwrite clean_username(self):

However I don't think this is getting called when I try to add a user from the admin. The auth.forms.py file is getting called even though I register my GUserAdmin.

Also, when I delete my database (sqlite3) and then call python manage.py syncdb, I see that a auth_user table is actually not getting created.

Yes, I have included AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have read:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms

Along with tons of SO posts but none of them seem to fix the issue I'm having.

Comment: Looks like this thread has your answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/kOVEy9zYn5c
  Apparently, Custom Model does not honor the `Meta` for manager

Comment: @karthikr I had seen that page but wasn't sure if we were having the same exact problem. Is the solution to actually change the code in auth.forms.py?

Comment: I think it is Scott Anderson's answer on March 20

Comment: Well if so please do confirm so I could mark this as an answer so it helps the future developers

Comment: Actually I implemented what Scott did in the page and I'm having the same issue. I think it might be that I actually do not have a auth_user table when I syncdb. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you dont care about the data in the db just drop the database and create it again.

Comment: Yea I have done that, and no user_auth is created even if I have the auth app installed.

Comment: 1)I have the same form and admin classes for my own custom user.
The only difference that a use my user model name instead of get_user_model(). I tried to replace model name to get_user_model() and everything works fine all the same.
2) user_auth table must not exist, this is correct that you don`t have it.

Problem is somewhere out of code you posted. Show please you full models, forms, admin files and you project settings

Comment: User_auth should not be created?
Then how can I use the auth app to authenticate my users? I should be able to do this, correct?
Something else to note: in my admin page, instead of "GUser" I get "User". This probably is the best indication of the problem. What could it be?

Comment: Instead of user_auth your model will have name app_name__user_model_name. "User" is not identificator, it is verbose name of model AbstractUser. As I wrote upper - need more info.

Comment: Have you added `django.contrib.auth` in your installed apps? What about the app that contains `GUser`? We need to see your `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So deleted all the work I had done with this and moved on with the standard user so that I could make progress. Then one day I went back to it and managed to get it working in an hour. 
I'll post the code for reference but I can't really pin point what made the difference. I do know that the creation forms and stuff were not necessary.

models.py

```
class PropaUser(AbstractUser):
    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from login.models import PropaUser

admin.site.register(PropaUser)
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "login.PropaUser"
```

other models.py

```
class Word(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    deck = models.ManyToManyField(Deck)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
    return self.word
```

This is what is working. I do not know what was causing all the issues before because I think I tried this method before posting this question. This may not be a satisfactory answer but this is what is working. Earlier I was also confused about what it takes simply to add a field to the existing User. This is it.

Comment: I have the same problem right now. It works when one doesn't register with something inherited from "UserAdmin".
`admin.site.register(GUser,GUserAdmin)` vs. `admin.site.register(PropaUser)`

Comment: When I tried this with Django 1.6, I ended up just being able to directly edit all the fields directly (including the built-in password field's hashed result)!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the error lies in incorrect zeroing of the database.
'Database error: no such table: str'

To delete the database, delete only database & all migrations in the migration packages(like 0001_initial.py and etc.).

Do not delete all migration packages and file "**init**.py". If you did this, create them. Django will not create them again.
And after, do not remember run makemigrations & migrate.